# How do I change the grails.exe console colors in Windows?

Tags: windows, grails

I run Grails 2.3.6 in Windows from a normal command prompt: "grails run-app"

By default Grails likes to use different colors for various types of textual output. That's fine, but what I really don't like are the Groovy exceptions which are displayed in **dark red**. I use a **black** background which make them difficult to read.

Cygwin is nice in that when Grails runs I don't see any colors at all (even exceptions), but Cygwin has a different problem: the FileWatcher doesn't detect changes I make to Groovy source code, so "hot deployments" don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable ANSI colour codes by :

```
grails --plain-output run-app
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use Cygwin take a look at [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/). It's good replacement for default cygwin terminal and you [can run cygwin environment here](https://superuser.com/questions/591206/how-do-i-configure-conemu-to-run-cygwin-bash). It also supports themes (there are couple of them out of the box) so grails exceptions should look better.